How to make ReadFile return one escape sequence at a time when reading from the Windows console?
In the following code I both turn off ENABLE_LINE_INPUT and turn on ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT:
var new_input_console_mode = original_input_console_mode;
new_input_console_mode &= ~@as(windows.DWORD, windows.ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);
new_input_console_mode &= ~@as(windows.DWORD, windows.ENABLE_INSERT_MODE);
new_input_console_mode &= ~@as(windows.DWORD, windows.ENABLE_LINE_INPUT);
new_input_console_mode &= ~@as(windows.DWORD, windows.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);
new_input_console_mode &= ~@as(windows.DWORD, windows.ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
new_input_console_mode |= windows.ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
new_input_console_mode |= windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT;
if (windows.SetConsoleMode(std.io.getStdIn().handle, new_input_console_mode) == 0) {
    return Error.ApplicationErrorInvalidStdIn;
}

Does turning off ENABLE_LINE_INPUT guarantee that each call to ReadFile returns a single character or escape sequence? Would, for example, the following always be valid?
var buf: [256]u8 = undefined;

event_loop: while (true) {
    const len = try console.in.read(&buf); // read() is a wrapper around ReadFile

    if (len == 1 and buf[0] == '\x11') { // CTRL + Q
        break :event_loop;
    }

    if (len > 0 and buf[0] == 0x1b) {
        // Handles ANSI escape codes
    }
}

If my current code doesn't necessarily work (I imagine it doesn't), what can I do to fix it? I'm interested in solutions insofar as they serve my ultimate goal of alleviating the need to robustly parse ANSI escape sequences.

You don't seem to be calling ReadFile at all. The code looks like it is using the programming language's standard I/O library. That presumably comes with its own set of guarantees.

@IInspectable Zig's (the language I'm using) read function is merely a wrapper around ReadFile on Windows.

@WilliamRyman if the language you're using is zig, the you should have tagged the question with [zig]. I've done it for you.
